# typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'format')

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, hardhat, uniswapv3, waffle

I am getting this error whenever I run my hardhat deploy script for uniswap pool contract :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'format')
at Function.from (/home/abdulaleem/token/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/interface.ts:1259:33)
at new ContractFactory (/home/abdulaleem/token/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/factory.ts:53:33)
at main (/home/abdulaleem/token/scripts/01-deploy-uniswap-contracts.js:39:17)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Command:

```
npx hardhat run --network mumbai scripts/01-deploy-uniswap-contracts.js
```

Here error occurs while at const MATIC = new ContractFactory():

```
 const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  const Matic = new ContractFactory(
    artifacts.MATIC.abi,
    artifacts.MATIC.bytecode,
    deployer
  );
  const matic = await Matic.deploy();
```

Here's the full code:

```
const { Contract, ContractFactory, utils, BigNumber } = require("ethers");
const MATIC = require("../matic.json");

const artifacts = {
  UniswapV3Factory: require("@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json"),
  SwapRouter: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/SwapRouter.sol/SwapRouter.json"),
  NFTDescriptor: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/libraries/NFTDescriptor.sol/NFTDescriptor.json"),
  NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.sol/NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.json"),
  NonfungiblePositionManager: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json"),
  MATIC,
};

const linkLibraries = ({ bytecode, linkReferences }, libraries) => {
  Object.keys(linkReferences).forEach((fileName) => {
    Object.keys(linkReferences[fileName]).forEach((contractName) => {
      if (!libraries.hasOwnProperty(contractName)) {
        throw new Error(`Missing link library name ${contractName}`);
      }
      const address = utils
        .getAddress(libraries[contractName])
        .toLowerCase()
        .slice(2);
      linkReferences[fileName][contractName].forEach(({ start, length }) => {
        const start2 = 2 + start * 2;
        const length2 = length * 2;
        bytecode = bytecode
          .slice(0, start2)
          .concat(address)
          .concat(bytecode.slice(start2 + length2, bytecode.length));
      });
    });
  });
  return bytecode;
};

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  const Matic = new ContractFactory(
    artifacts.MATIC.abi,
    artifacts.MATIC.bytecode,
    deployer
  );
  const matic = await Matic.deploy();

  Factory = new ContractFactory(
    artifacts.UniswapV3Factory.abi,
    artifacts.UniswapV3Factory.bytecode,
    deployer
  );
  factory = await Factory.deploy();

  SwapRouter = new ContractFactory(
    artifacts.SwapRouter.abi,
    artifacts.SwapRouter.bytecode,
    deployer
  );
  swapRouter = await SwapRouter.deploy(factory.address, matic.address);

  NFTDescriptor = new ContractFactory(
    artifacts.NFTDescriptor.abi,
    artifacts.NFTDescriptor.bytecode,
    deployer
  );
  nftDescriptor = await NFTDescriptor.deploy();

  const linkedBytecode = linkLibraries(
    {
      bytecode: artifacts.NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.bytecode,
      linkReferences: {
        "NFTDescriptor.sol": {
          NFTDescriptor: [
            {
              length: 20,
              start: 1261,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      NFTDescriptor: nftDescriptor.address,
    }
  );

  NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor = new ContractFactory(
    artifacts.NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.abi,
    linkedBytecode,
    deployer
  );
  nonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor =
    await NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.deploy(matic.address);

  NonfungiblePositionManager = new ContractFactory(
    artifacts.NonfungiblePositionManager.abi,
    artifacts.NonfungiblePositionManager.bytecode,
    deployer
  );
  nonfungiblePositionManager = await NonfungiblePositionManager.deploy(
    factory.address,
    matic.address,
    nonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.address
  );

  console.log("Martic_ADDRESS=", `'${matic.address}'`);
  console.log("FACTORY_ADDRESS=", `'${factory.address}'`);
  console.log("SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS=", `'${swapRouter.address}'`);
  console.log("NFT_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS=", `'${nftDescriptor.address}'`);
  console.log(
    "POSITION_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS=",
    `'${nonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.address}'`
  );
  console.log(
    "POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS=",
    `'${nonfungiblePositionManager.address}'`
  );
}

/*
npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/01_deployContracts.js
*/

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Here's hardhat.config.js file:

```
 require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
    require("dotenv").config();
    require("hardhat-deploy");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL;
const MUMBAI_RPC_URL = process.env.MUMBAI_RPC_URL;
const Private_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const Private_KEY_USER = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_USER;
const Etherscan_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;
const POLYGON_SCAN_API_KEY = process.env.POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY;

module.exports = {
  defaultNetworks: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [Private_KEY],
      chainId: 11155111,
      blockConfirmations: 6,
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: MUMBAI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [Private_KEY, Private_KEY_USER],
      chainId: 80001,
      blockConfirmations: 6,
    },
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/",
      chainId: 31337,
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      polygonMumbai: POLYGON_SCAN_API_KEY,
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.8.20" }, { version: "0.7.6" }],
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    //by default 0th account is deployer
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
    user: {
      default: 1,
    },
  },

  settings: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 5000,
      details: { yul: false },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'format')

the variables are either undefined or not formatted proparly for the function to interpret the arguments.

I think the problem either lies with matic.abi or the matic.bytecode which might not be read or formatted properly from the matic.json file.

Would need to know the matic.json file

Comment: Yes, you are right I found the solution. I didn't add bytecode in matic.jason. Thank you for solution